# how to solve "Error during parsing. could not instantiate" in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Hello every one i am new in Pig i am trying following pig script :

then it shows following error :
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. could not instantiate 'UPER' with arguments 'null' Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1371303109105.log

my Pig script:

```
register udf.jar; 
A = LOAD 'data1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, class:chararray, age:int);
B = foreach A generate UPER(class);
```

I follow [this](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html) tutorial .

My java class is :

```
enter code here


import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import java.io.*;

public class UPER extends EvalFunc<String>{

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(input == null ||input.size() ==0)
         return null;
         try
         {
            String str=(String)input.get(0); 
            return str.toUpperCase(); 
         }
          catch(Exception e){
              throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);


          }}
}
```

Comment: Can you paste **/home/training/pig_1371303109105.log**?

Comment: Hello  zsxwing thanxx for replay on my question i am not able to post my whole content here so i put it on paste bin can you please see it there and tell me why this error occur in my code please..
http://pastebin.com/zrdRkSkg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following information from your error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        The type org.apache.commons.logging.Log cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

        at UPER.<init>(UPER.java:1)
```

I guess that `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` is not in your environment. How did you run your Pig script? This class should have been in the Pig envrionment. `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` is in `commons-logging-*.*.*.jar`

Comment: I am using Cloudera for training sir

Comment: So you are using its web interface to run the Pig script?

Comment: noo sir i am running it on terminal and grunt shell on local mode sir.

Comment: Sir i have to register all those jar which i use in my udf code like pig jar and commons

Comment: I found the solution of my problem is that i have to add an all jar file with in the project workspace of in eclipse all jar like for pig, commons-lang3-3.1, commons-logging-1.1.3.jar well thats all and i search it so many time but not get my answer the i do all thing from start and get my answer Thank you zsxwing for giving time to my question your answer really help me a lot.. thank you all

Comment: Actually, when I use "pig -f abc.pig" to run the script, the jars which pig uses do not need to be added. Sorry that I don't know why you need to do it.

Comment: Sir my udf is not work that time but when i add all of them then it start working sir But your answer really help me a lot..